# How to save all buffers in vim (even if they haven't changed)?

Tags: vim, latex

I have this particular problem as i use the vim-latex-live-preview-plugin which recompiles my .tex document everytime it is written to disk. So my workflow is the following:

- make some changes
- hit `:w`
- see changes in pdf.

However, now I'm working on a larger document where I make use of the `\input{example_input}` command. My current workflow is

- work in example_input.tex
- save example_input.tex with `:w`
- switch buffer to "root" tex file
- save "root" text file
  *) entire document is recompiled
  *) switch back to buffer I'm actually working in (example_input.tex).

This is clearly undesirable. 
First, I thought `:wa` does what I want, but unfortunately `:wa` only writes to disk if the buffer has actually changed (unlike `:w`).
Is there something like `:wa` (save all buffers) with the behavior of `:w` (write to disk even if buffer didn't change)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `:h :wa` says (emphasis added):

```
                            *:wa* *:wall*
:wa[ll]         Write all CHANGED buffers.  Buffers without a file
            name cause an error message.  Buffers which are
            readonly are not written. {not in Vi}
```

Fortunately, there's an easy way to force vim to write every buffer, even the ones that haven't changed. Try this command:

```
:bufdo w
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [README](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview#configuration) of vim-latex-live-preview. Does this help?

> If the root file is not the file you are currently editing, you can specify it by executing :LLPStartPreview  or executing :LLPStartPreview with the following declaration in the first line of your source file:
>
> `% !TEX root = <root-filename>`

Comment: I saw this but didn't think too much of it. However, you're probably right, this should be the way to go.